# Display immediate searched result from long process in Struts2 before finish

Tags: java, performance, jquery, struts2

I'm doing a program in Struts2 that is parsing some xml from some list of urls and store the list of beans in HttpSession. This is a long running process, because it has to download xml from url, parse it, and create bean. I want to design this task such a manner so that when it will get request from client, it will start parsing and store the result in session. When it finishes parsing some xml it notify the page or Struts from java so that it able to show some results before all parsing the rest of url being completed. I'm already using this parsing in different thread. But it has risk, because web manages different thread pool for each different client request and it has the possibility of memory leak. I already have a look in [execAndWait](http://www.journaldev.com/2296/struts2-execandwait-interceptor-example-for-long-running-actions)
, but it is not possible to display some result bean during parsing process.
Any one can tell better way or better solution.

Comment: Creating beans from XML... are you sure it is *that* long ?

Comment: Yes it is long, but not too much. Some times it takes more than three minutes to parse 15 large xml after downloading from web. Has it any way that I can manage parsing mechanism by a loop or other else so that after parsing one xml, I can able to display immediate result without breaking all parsing process being finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. First of all create an interceptor project and extends ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.java instead of Interceptor interface and override doIntercept method. Just we have to use  [getNewBackgroundProcess()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.0.12/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.java) in doIntercept method. This method mainly create a background thread. If you control this interceptor, then we don't need to wait for uncertain delay. If we control this mechanism then we can call intermediate page when one bean is ready to display before long process being finished. All control will be in my hand, when it should be called. And we don't need to use delay and interval delay, because any bean might not be ready to display after this delay.